# Pass parameters to function in prefix notation

Tags: scala

Having a function F and a parameter P, you usually say F(P). However, I am looking for a notation for P.applyTo(F).

I know that I can build an implicit class to do the magic. But, is there anything builtin?

Comment: About the implicit class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651240/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the built-in support for postFix? You might have a look in `language.postFix` but it's not necessary to import it to use it. Methods ending with `:` as in `List(1, 2, 3) ::: List(4, 5, 6)` which invokes a `prepend` method on the `List(4, 5, 6)`, creating `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`. The extra `:` at the end of the method name stands for the postfix application.

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a1 = A("first")
    val a2 = A("second")
    val res = a1 >> a2
    val res2 = a1 >>: a2
    println(res) //yields "firstsecond"
    println(res2) //yields "secondfirst"
  }

  case class A(name: String) {
    def >>:(a: A): String = name + a.name
    def >>(a: A): String = name + a.name
  }
}
```